# Does grenadine need to be refrigerated?

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator, cocktails

I've been looking for a bottle of [Rose's](http://www.rosesmix.com/) Grenadine for quite a while without luck, so when I saw a big ol' liter of [Llord's](http://www.citywinecellar.com/store/product/5505/Llords-Grenadine-1L/) at the liquor store, I grabbed it. I'm not sure I want to allocate that much fridge space to it though. Can I keep it behind the bar instead?

[Sugar is a preservative](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/312545#4362352) and there's a little bit of alcohol in it too, so my guess is it's ok on the shelf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure about other types of grenadine, but assuming they're the same as Rose's, they do *not* need to be refrigerated.

It's not just that they *contain* sugar - they're practically nothing *but* sugar, water, and a couple of "chemicals."  There's really nothing in there that can spoil, unless you put something else into the bottle that wasn't there originally.

Unless you accidentally dropped a piece of chicken in there, definitely don't worry about refrigeration.  It can sit on the shelf.

Comment: Oh... I accidentally drop chicken into my alcohol all the time... no wonder I get sick.

Comment: FYI, the grenadine you buy in stores such as Rose's generally doesn't contain any alcohol.  It's like sour mix or margarita mix - just a mixer, not a liqueur.

Answer (score 4):

I called the number on the label.  The shelf life of Rose's grenadine is 6 months REFRIGERATED.  I had been storing mine in my liquor cabinet for awhile, he told me that it should be good as long as it doesn't smell funky.  None of these high-sugar content products really go 'bad' in the traditional sense.

Comment: up-vote for using the phone--something I never do ;)